# Run console Asynchronously to result a more efficient output

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, console-application, async-await

```
class CommandLine2
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}", args.Length);

    foreach (string s in args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
}
```

This is an example of the console app that will fire the task from a WCF.

I got a project that fires a set of check on csv files line by line and I am creating a console app that will do the task. What I need is to run this async so it will hit each row and after say around few seconds end the task. I want it to be efficient that's why. I will be using a WCF so if you know a way to run the command async please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WCF, you should be able to make the client server reference include Task-based asynchronous client calls.

You'd then just need to call the operation(s) asynchronously.

Given that you're working in a console application, however, you may not want to use `async`/`await`, and instead just fire off the operations, and use `Task.WaitAll` or similar.  The problem with  async operations in a console app is that there is no current synchronization context, so you need to be careful not to let the application shut down until your async work is completed.

Comment: So where would I apply the Task.WaitALL?

Comment: @MohammedTahir After you've started all of the tasks - that will block the client until they've all completed.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant where would i write it? is it on the consol inside the loop or in the WCF?

Comment: @MohammedTahir In the console app, outside of the loop, probably.