# run console task asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;



namespace NewTask
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NewTask.Combine taskcombine = new NewTask.Combine();
            ProfileClient profilesws = new ProfileClient();
            var profileRecords = profilesws.GetAllProfiles();
            foreach (var profile in profileRecords.ProfileRecords)
            {
                var testProfile = new NewTask.Profile();
                testProfile.Id = profile.Id;
                testProfile.Name = profile.Name;


                var result = taskcombine.TestProfile(testProfile);

            }


            profilesws.Close();
            taskcombine.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I want a way to run this async. I want to hit the ruslt and once it goes through all the records into result I want it to end the task. This will be a consol app and once the results are filled with the required records I would like it to close the app asynchronously.

Comment: Do you really want Asynchronously or are you really looking for Parallel? Because if it is async what other work is going to be done while the task is running? Can `taskcombine.TestProfile` be run from multiple threads safely? Why are you returning result if you are not doing anything with it?

Comment: How is this different to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388419/run-console-asynchronously-to-result-a-more-efficient-output ?

Comment: I don't want it to wait till it goes through the full loop. I would like it to run async and once the result is filled close the app and not wait for the rest.

Comment: So you only care about the first itteration to produce a result? Does `TestProfile()` have a async version that returns a `Task` or will you need to start tasks up yourself?

Comment: yes that's right @ScottChamberlain I only care about the first itteration to produce result and I will be running the task my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TestProfile` has a `TestProfileAsync` version that returns a Task your code would be

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NewTask.Combine taskcombine = new NewTask.Combine();
        ProfileClient profilesws = new ProfileClient();
        var profileRecords = profilesws.GetAllProfiles();

        var tasks = new List<Task<ResultClass>>();

        foreach (var profile in profileRecords.ProfileRecords)
        {
            var testProfile = new NewTask.Profile();
            testProfile.Id = profile.Id;
            testProfile.Name = profile.Name;

            tasks.Add(taskcombine.TestProfileAsync(testProfile))
        }

        int completedIndex = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());

        var result = tasks[completedIndex].Result;

        profilesws.Close();
        taskcombine.Close();
    }
}
```

If the function does not have an async version you will need to wrap it in your own Task.

```
tasks.Add(Task<ResultClass>.Factory.Start(() => taskcombine.TestProfile(testProfile)));
```

This is all assuming that `taskcombine.TestProfile` is thread safe. If it is not thread safe you will need to explain more what `taskcombine.TestProfile` does and if you can make multiple instance of it

```
tasks.Add(Task<ResultClass>.Factory.Start(() => 
{
     NewTask.Combine taskcombine = new NewTask.Combine(); //Move the declaration inside the task so a new Combine gets created per task.
     return taskcombine.TestProfile(testProfile);
}));
```

---

**EDIT**: One other tweak you can do is use a [cancellation token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) so if you have a result already before some of the tasks even start they will not start at all.

First, dream solution with an async version of TestProfileAsync that has the signature `Task<ResultClass> TestProfileAsync(NewTask.Profile a, CancllationToken token)`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NewTask.Combine taskcombine = new NewTask.Combine();
        ProfileClient profilesws = new ProfileClient();
        var profileRecords = profilesws.GetAllProfiles();

        var tasks = new List<Task<ResultClass>>();
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cts.Token;            

        foreach (var profile in profileRecords.ProfileRecords)
        {
            var testProfile = new NewTask.Profile();
            testProfile.Id = profile.Id;
            testProfile.Name = profile.Name;

            tasks.Add(taskcombine.TestProfileAsync(testProfile, token))
        }

        int completedIndex = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());

        //This should stop any tasks before they even start.
        cts.Cancel();

        var result = tasks[completedIndex].Result;

        profilesws.Close();
        taskcombine.Close();
    }
}
```

If you don't have access to an async version, here is the 4.5 version of the code with tasks

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NewTask.Combine taskcombine = new NewTask.Combine();
        ProfileClient profilesws = new ProfileClient();
        var profileRecords = profilesws.GetAllProfiles();

        var tasks = new List<Task<ResultClass>>();
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cts.Token;            

        foreach (var profile in profileRecords.ProfileRecords)
        {
            var testProfile = new NewTask.Profile();
            testProfile.Id = profile.Id;
            testProfile.Name = profile.Name;

            //If the token is canceled before the task gets to start itself it should never start and go stright to the "Canceled" state.
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => 
                       {
                           token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); //In case the task started but we did get a result before the last 
                           return taskcombine.TestProfile(testProfile); //Assumes "taskcombine.TestProfile(...)" is thread safe.
                       }, token));
        }

        var result = Task.WhenAny(tasks).Result;

        //This should stop any tasks that have not spun up yet from spinning up
        cts.Cancel();

        profilesws.Close();
        taskcombine.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: All this code uses 4.0 classes. If you are using 4.5 you can do things like `tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => taskcombine.TestProfile(testProfile)));` and `Task.WhenAny(tasks).Result` to simplify the code.